# CSS for this weird type of shadow?

Tags: css, shadow

I'm having some trouble making a shadow like the one in the attached image. Does anyone have any suggestions about the CSS for this shadow?

[IMAGE - EXAMPLE SHADOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWzTC.png)

Comment: Looks like a vanilla *css box shadow* to me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this codepen for some standard material design box shadow presets
[Codepen Material Design Box Shadow](https://codepen.io/sdthornton/pen/wBZdXq)

The following is shorthand for box shadow property

```
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
```

MDN's doc on box-shadow [Mozilla Developer Network Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)